# Notepad++ Find And replace :

Tags: notepad++

So here is an example `100.7.34.243:31499` I want to replace the numbers after : with : too. I don't know how because I am kind of a noob so please don't hate I haven't tried anything yet because I don't know how.

Comment: I think Notepad++ find and replace supports Regex. Lookup regexes if you don't know how to use them.

Comment: Notepad++ does support RegEx - it's the bottom option in the `Ctrl+F` popup dialog.  Also, not a programming question unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the way to do the job:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `:\d+`
- Replace with: `:too`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

Make sure to check `Regular expression`

Answer (score 0):

For do this you have to follow these step:

Select the text from replace

Go on `Search -> Replace` in `Replace with` put text that you want replace

Click on Replace.

Here the screen: 
Go here for [screen](http://imgur.com/a/gJ9QQ)